# How to make this circuit pass all conditions

Tags: capacitor, pulse

I have this circuit (as part of a larger design):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2am1B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistors are with a tolerance of 1%.

On the input, *V1*, the circuit **gets a pulse whose initial voltage is 28V** to a certain voltage (shown later), with the *Ton* of the pulse being at a certain length (shown later).

The reference voltages are created using a micropower voltage reference IC and op-amps.

I need to make sure that when inputting these pulses, some will assert **out2** to '0' and some will make it remain at '1'. (Please note that out1 is not really important here, I just included it in the schematic so you will know it is there).

Here are the voltages and pulse lengths that I am inputting to *V1*:

```
Out2 Should Remain at '1'      Out2 Should Assert to '0'
30V/80mSec                     30V/100mSec
40V/10mSec                     40V/20mSec
50V/5mSec                      50V/10mSec
```

The capacitor *C1* is what concerns me. **I don't know how to determine it's value.** It is a SMT ceramic capacitor.

From what I understand, the capacitor has two jobs:

1. Filter spikes from the power supply (the P.S is a generator).
2. Provide timing (together with the resistors), so that certain pulses with certain lengths will assert Out2 to '0'.

The thing is, I have tried so many options for the capacitor and none seem to work for all conditions. I have tried both in simulation and in real life, and of course it doesn't always seem to match...

If I use too small capacitor (for example 1uF), then Vc will reach 3.62V too quickly, and **Out2** will be '0' when it's supposed to be at '1'. If I use too big capacitor (for example 4.7uF), then Vc won't reach 3.62V, even at 30V/100mSec, meaning **Out2** will not be '0' as intended, and so will remain at '1'. (I am 99% sure that I used LTSpice to simulate this circuit with a 4.7uF capacitor and it actually asserted Out2 to '0', but it did not happen with the actual device when I soldered a 4.7uF capacitor)

So here are my questions:

1. Lets assume I can use a capacitor and be done with it. How can I determine it's value? I have tried calculations and simulations and experimented with lots of capacitor values and none seem to work for all conditions.
2. Is there a solution that is smarter than just using a capacitor? Do note that the PCB already exists so I can't change my design too much, so using ICs is somewhat of a problem. I would however love to hear about these solutions, if they exist, both because I would see if it can somehow be implemented and because I would like to learn.

Thank you very much!

**Edit:**

\$V(t) = V(inf) - (V(inf)-V(0))e^(-t/Tau)\$

\$V(t) = 3.62V\$

\$V(inf) = 3.68V\$ (Because of voltage divider when input is at 30V)

\$V(0) = 3.43V\$ (Because of voltage divider when input is at 28V)

\$t = 92mSec\$ (fall time is 5mSec so I took a margin)

At the end of my calculations I got:

\$Tau = 64.46mSec\$

\$Tau = R1||R2*C = 11.14k*C = 64.46m\$

\$C = 5.786uF\$

But this result does not help me, as like I said, for 4.7uF, Everything passed except 30V/100mSec.

Comment: Using the standard exponential formula for a charging capacitor have you calculated what voltage is reached with the pulses described?

Comment: In my calculations, I used the 3.62V as reference and tried to find the right capacitor through that. So for example, I tried to calculate the right **tau** for 75msec (a bit less than 80msec) and through that, find the capacitor.

Comment: Also, since **tau** is RC, my R was actually R1||R2. I hope it's correct.

Comment: So please reveal those values.

Comment: @Andyaka which values? In my schematic I have shown the values of R1, R2, and in the table I have shown the values of the voltages and pulse lengths. It is the capacitor which is a variable here, and I need to find it.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but I'll edit my post to show one of the calculations (30V/100msec), to illustrate how I tried to do it.

Comment: @Andyaka I added calculations. Please tell me if they make sense to you, thank you. Sorry for the not really good formatting, I don't really know how to use MathJax.

Comment: Can you use a spreadsheet? You could put each scenario into excel for instance and have them all share the same value of capacitor (that you can modify) and see what the final voltage is for each scenario. Fiddle with the capacitor value until all scenarios meet the requirements of exceeding 3.62 volts.

Comment: @Andyaka that sounds like a process that could be completed with the Solver, voltages that have to be within specific ranges ie criteria and the capacitor value as objective...

Comment: @Andyaka it's a nice idea, must say I haven't thought of that, but isn't it better (more accurate) to use a simulator and just change capacitor values? Since I already tried the simulator idea, I'm not really sure how a spreadsheet would help.

Comment: I am way more inclined to use smarter solutions for this problem. Are there not any that I can implement via a re-work on the PCB?